# Proper conversion of contrib.HashTable usage in TF 2

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a Keras layer that takes a string input and returns a series of indices into an embedding matrix. The code for testing the TF 1.x version is [here](https://gist.github.com/zmjjmz/2ee2090233217c0d1be2dc975e5c3a47), and the theoretically-TF2-compatible testing code is [here](https://gist.github.com/zmjjmz/81138b0d62764fabe00085cd7091dd14).

The TF2 version doesn't work, and it seems that my issues center around initializing the table. In the old version I need to run the `tables_initializer` (although I believe Keras.fit does this), but this isn't really something that you can do in TF2 -- both because there's no table_initializer and also because there's no access (afaict) to explicit Sessions.

So when I run the TF 2 version of this, I need to figure out how to run the initializer on the call to `keras.layer.build`. The most obvious way to do this is to follow the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/lookup/StaticHashTable#class_statichashtable) which directs `StaticHashTable.init.run()` -- this is completely [incorrect](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26497) however.

So if I don't do any of this (on the assumption that it will somehow magically work), I get a `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Table not initialized.`

So, an alternative: `init` just [returns the initializer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/ops/lookup_ops.py#L326), so I could instead take the table's initializer and do: `KeyValueInitializer.initialize(StatisHashTable).run()`, but this still requires a default Session to be registered, which, even if possible, does not seem like idiomatic TF 2 (and I haven't figured out how to get a 'Session' anyways). The specific error I get is `ValueError: Cannot execute operation using 'run()': No default session is registered. Use 'with sess.as_default():' or pass an explicit session to 'run(session=sess)'`.

So that's a dead end. I've tried some other stuff that I'm fairly certain are not 'how you are supposed to do it' in TF 2 like wrapping the initializer Operator in `control_dependencies` or giving that its `run` method a session from `compat.v1.keras.backend.get_session()` all to no avail.

I'd like to believe that the `tf.lookup.StaticHashTable` works somehow in TF 2, but I'm just not sure how to make it work -- anyone have any advice?

Comment: Any update? I'm going through similar stuff of exporting keras model with some tables to tf2.x. I can't use `tf.compat.v1.tables_initializer()` in tf2 and not sure what other stuff I can use there